# memory alignment - Sparc(Sun) cc compiler, Intel(Linux) g++ compiler, Intel(Windows) MVSC compiler

Tags: c++, algorithm, architecture, g++, memory-alignment

My question is composed of 2 parts.

1. I noticed that memalign(block_size,bytes) on sparc(sun) with a cc compiler doesn't check that bytes is a power of 2 as opposed to memalign on intel linux and _aligned_malloc on windows with mvsc compiler that do check that bytes are a power of 2.

is this a bug in a sun, is there a patch or i need to write a memalign by my self.

1. Additionally i have a structure (not my code):

   ```
   typedef struct CLHLockStruct {
       volatile CLHLockNode CACHE_ALIGN *Tail ;
       volatile CLHLockNode CACHE_ALIGN *MyNode[N_THREADS] ;
       volatile CLHLockNode CACHE_ALIGN *MyPred[N_THREADS] ;
   } CLHLockStruct;
   ```

I am compiling under MVSC (visual studio 2008):

```
    CACHE_LINE_SIZE = 64
    CACHE_ALIGN = __declspec(align(CACHE_LINE_SIZE)) 
    N_THREADS = 8
    sizeof(CLHLockStruct)=192
```

The code has been written initially for a sparc architecture, and i try to migrate it to MVSC without changing to much code.

in their code they use memalign(CACHE_LINE_SIZE,sizeof(CLHLockStruct)), and i have changed it to _aligned_malloc , my problem is that sizeof(CLHLockStruct) is not a power of 2, i may write some function that finds the next number that is a power of 2.

Is their a better approach ?

**EDIT1**

How may i padd this struct so that its size will be a power of 2?

**EDIT2**

Is there a function that acts like _aligned_malloc  and malloc : returns a memory pointer aligned to the multiple of block_size but doesn't require the bytes to be a power of 2?

Comment: `cc` is a symbolic link on linux. What are the compilers and which version ?

Comment: Sorry , i had a small mistake, the compiler on linux is g++ (gcc version 4.4.3) i have edited the title and added a tag

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> in their code they use memalign(CACHE_LINE_SIZE,sizeof(CLHLockStruct)), and i have changed it to _aligned_malloc , my problem is that sizeof(CLHLockStruct) is not a power of 2,

Did you change it to `_aligned_malloc(CACHE_LINE_SIZE,sizeof(CLHLockStruct))`? Yes, that would cause this. [`_aligned_malloc`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8z34s9c6%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) expects the size as its first argument, and the alignment as the second, the opposite of `memalign`, so you need to swap the arguments. The size does not need to be a power of two.

Answer (score 1):

**Answer 1:** The [POSIX standard defines memalign](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/) to return a power of two *and* a multiple of the system's pointer size. But it also requires the blocksize parameter to be a power of two. Is that the case for your code? Could also be that your Win library does not fully comply with POSIX in this case.

**Answer 2:** [This SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1322510/given-an-integer-how-do-i-find-the-next-largest-power-of-two-using-bit-twiddlin) lists a couple of ways of determining the next power of two, which you may use in your aligned_malloc implementation.

**Answer 3:** I (better: Google) found another post that explains [padding a struct to a multiple of a power of two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1239855/pad-a-c-structure-to-a-power-of-two).

Comment: I will go over answer 2,3 , it seems very relevant to me, although i preferred some pragma directive if there is one. as regards to answer 1, It is not my code, and it seems that they demand the structure size to be a power of 2 in-order that memalign will work, although initially this code was intend to be on a sparc architecture, and if you check the size of the structure their it is not a power of 2, it seems that they had a bug in their code, but the bug in memalign on sparc(sun) cc compiler may not reviled it.

Comment: Sure, that may be the case. I was just trying to give hints on what may be wrong. ;)

Comment: i have edited my question with one more suggestion, could you answer it?